# PHP cURL from input file

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the HTTP response of some website.

I will have check about 30000 of them daily for about 6 month and the list will be updated daily so I would like to be able to read in the URLs from a file.

This is what works no file:

```
<?php
$url1 = 'http://www.google.com';
$url2 = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
$url3 = 'http://www.bing.com';

$s = get_headers($url1, 1);
$y = get_headers($url2, 1);
$z = get_headers($url3, 1);

$g = $s[0];
$h = $y[0];
$i = $z[0];

echo $url1 . " - " . $g . "\n";
echo $url2 . " - " . $h . "\n";
echo $url3 . " - " . $i . "\n";
?>
```

Sample Output:

```
http://www.google.com - HTTP/1.0 200 OK
http://www.yahoo.com - HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
http://www.bing.com - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Now when I try to run the same with a file and a for each loop I get the file output but no response. What am I doing wrong.

I have checked the array output and all looks good.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$file_lines = file('urls.txt');

foreach ($file_lines as $line) {
    $s = get_headers($line, 1);
    $g = $s[0];
    echo $line . " - " . $g . "\n";
}
?>
```

urls.txt:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

Sample Output:

```
http://www.google.com
 -
http://www.yahoo.com
 -
http://www.bing.com
 -
```

With Errors turned off I am getting an error and have tried a bunch of fixes but am still stumped.

Sample Output:

```
PHP Warning:  get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  get_headers(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
http://www.google.com
 -
PHP Warning:  get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  get_headers(http://www.yahoo.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
http://www.yahoo.com
 -
PHP Warning:  get_headers(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  get_headers(http://www.bing.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/testsites.php on line 23
http://www.bing.com
 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the file() function reads the newline character from the urls.txt file. All urls would add a newline character at the end of each line.

Example:
http://www.google.com => http://www.google.com/n

Solution:
Add FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES to omits newline.

`$file_lines = file('urls.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$file_lines = file('urls.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($file_lines as $line) {
    $s = get_headers($line, 1);
    $g = $s[0];
    echo $line . " - " . $g . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading the lines from the file, you are also getting a newline character which is being included in the address for `get_headers()`.

Use

```
$file_lines = file('urls.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

To strip off the new lines in your addresses and things should work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0):

It is because each line has line ending. You can use `trim` function to remove it.

```
$file_lines = file('urls.txt');

foreach ($file_lines as $line) {
    $s = get_headers(trim($line), 1);
    $g = $s[0];
    echo $line . " - " . $g . "\n";
}
```